# NameError: name 'Name' is not defined in django form

Tags: python, django

I want to render the following form but django throws out a error and i dont understand why. Thanks in advance.

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import equipment 



class neweqForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = equipment

    name = forms.CharField(label=Name, max_lenght=100) 
    fabricator = forms.CharField(label=Hersteller, max_lenght=100) 
    storeplace = forms.IntegerField(label=Regal) 
    labour = forms.ChoiceField(label=Gewerk)
```

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class equipment(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    fabricator = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    storeplace = models.IntegerField() 
    labor_choices = (  
        ('L', 'Licht'), 
        ('T', 'Ton'), 
        ('R', 'rigging'),
    ) 
    labor = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=labor_choices)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'Name' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having `label` for each field, but you are using `Name`, `Hersteller`, etc to assign the value. You might have major misunderstanding about variables and strings. If you don't quote something, they are treated as variables in python. But they not defined anywhere else, so python let you know that those are undefined variables.

Quick fixes would be adding quotes around all label values:

```
name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_lenght=100)
```

You just pasted the error from the traceback, great, but you need to learn how to read the traceback going forward. If you read the traceback backwards, it tells you what are each function that's called that lead the ultimate error. I'm pretty sure that the line `name = forms.CharField(label=Name, max_lenght=100)` shows up in the end(if your calling something else it might be in the middle) which tells you that that's the location where error happens. You would benefit from this a lot while tracing the errors.